# WordPress Amend Body Class

Tags: html, css, wordpress, class

I want to add -wp to the beginning of ALL the body classes which WordPress adds using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

The reason for this is because I sometimes want to use classes like .attachment or .page from the root of the CSS document and as it is the body class it clashes.

The codex shows me how to add classes to the body but not how I can add to each individual class it adds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding an action on body_class hook.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_class_names' );
function my_class_names( $classes ) {
  // You have all the classes in $classes
  // Iterate and add the wp prefix.
  $new_classes = array();
  foreach($classes as $cls) {
    $new_classes[] = 'wp-' . $cls;
  }

   return $new_classes;
}
```

The code is not tested, but it should work.

Comment: Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\post-template.php on line 682

Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\post-template.php on line 499

Comment: This outputs them as normal - do I need to do anything to this code? I am unsure with 'you have all the classes in $classes' if you mean I need to enter the classes or it gets them automatically?

Comment: It should get them automatically. Certainly is that the body_class hook exists. Test the function and see that the parameter gives you.

Comment: It gets them all: single single-post postid-93 single-format-standard logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support  -  it just doesn't add the wp-